# Blob constructor Safari issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, safari

I am using JQuery blob to export the JQuery array to CSV.
It is working on every browser except on Safari 5.1.7.
Safari browser on Windows 7.
I came to Know Blob has compatibility issues with Safari.
please let me know if there is any work around to achieve it.

Below is the code:

```
var usersCSVData = [];
usersCSVData.push('LastName ','FirstName ', 'Login ','City ','State','Location ');  

 var fileName = "UserCSVdata.csv";
 var buffer = usersCSVData.join("\n");
 var blob = new Blob([buffer], {
                    "type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"
                });


         if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
         else {
             var link = document.createElement("a");
             if (link.download !== undefined) {

                 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                 link.setAttribute("href", url);
                 link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
                 link.style = "visibility:hidden";
                 document.body.appendChild(link);
                 link.click();
                 document.body.removeChild(link);
             }
            }
```

I am getting error:

```
"'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([buffer], {

                    "type": "text/csv;charset=utf8;"

                })')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `BlobBuilder` or `WebKitBlobBuilder` first. Also such using blob constructors/builders solve some problems in `Android Stock Browser` 4.4-:

```js
//cross browser BlobBuilder constructor
var customBlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
//result
var blob;
//Data
var buffer = ['LastName ','FirstName ', 'Login ','City ','State','Location '].join("\n");

//Try to use WebKitBlobBuilder first, It also solves some issues for Android Stock Browser
if (window.WebKitBlobBuilder) {
  blob = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
  blob.append(buffer);
  blob = blob.getBlob("text/csv");
} else if (window.Blob) {
  blob = new Blob([buffer], { type : "text/csv" });
} else {
  blob = new customBlobBuilder();
  blob.append(buffer);
  blob = blob.getBlob("text/csv");
}
console.log(blob);
```

Comment: If you run this snippet inside Safari and look at the console (referring to console.log in the answer), you will see that the same error the OP stated is shown. I am also searching for this answer.